# Connect to Windows via Samba - instant timeouts

Tags: networking, samba

I'm trying to connect ElementaryOS to a Windows laptop and nothing I've tried has worked. Even running gvfs-mount smb://192.168.1.x from the terminal results in "Error mounting location: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out"

Should Samba work out of the box in ElementaryOS or are there post-install steps? I know this share works because I can connect to it on my laptop which is running Manjaro. Its just ElementaryOS that refuses to connect to it.